# ASP.NET Validators working locally but not hosted on IIS 6.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

Running visual studio 2012. The website targets .NET 2.0.

I have these asp:RequiredFieldValidator's and asp:CustomValidator's hooked up to asp:TextBox's.

They fire correctly locally on IIS Express in debug mode but not when I host it in IIS 6.0 on a server box. The hosted application skips these front-end validators altogether.

There is a javascript function associated with asp:CustomValidator and it never steps into the code on the hosted instance (verified with Firebug Firefox extension).

Any idea why these validators are not working correctly? Or how to find out why?

Comment: Does the JavaScript for the RequiredFieldValidator also fail when hosted from the server box? Try running Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see if there are any 404 or 500 errors being returned when the page requests ScriptResource.axd and/or WebResource.axd files. Also check your App_Browsers folder to see if it is different from your dev version -- ASP.Net will sometimes disable JavaScript output if it thinks the browser doesn't support it.

Comment: Is there any script errors shown in firebug or perhaps some scripts not loading correctly, do you see any errors in firebug console?

Comment: Jordan you are onto something - Missing some 2 WebResource.axd files - I also have no idea what these are.

Comment: Seems likely that these 2 css style definitions are the problem - .ajax__calendar_prev {cursor:pointer;width:15px;height:15px;float:left;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:50% 50%;background-image:url(<%=WebResource("AjaxControlToolkit.Calendar.arrow-left.gif")%>);} AND
.ajax__calendar_next {cursor:pointer;width:15px;height:15px;float:right;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:50% 50%;background-image:url(<%=WebResource("AjaxControlToolkit.Calendar.arrow-right.gif")%>);}

Comment: Still a bit confused how to fix this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: s|WebForms.js and s|WebUIValidation.js seem to be what is missing on the server instance of the app...getting closer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 days of hunting. It was because of this "Verify File Exists" checkbox on .axd files in the IIS Default Web Site settings.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2008/12/04/webresource-axd-or-scriptresource-axd-not-working.aspx